# Allowing for wildcard at end of url for javascript conditional css style

Tags: javascript, css, url, conditional-statements, wildcard

I have a script working that switches stylesheet depending on the url.

It has to be done this way because the site uses smarty templates and I don't want to alter the core files or the core css.

Right now I have to add the URL pathname of each individual page. The more pages there are, the more impractical this is.

So for example, instead of `/ojs/index.php/index/user/register` and `/ojs/index.php/index/user/profile` I would like to call `/ojs/index.php/index/user/*` so then all pages under `/user/` would have the stylesheet applied to them.

What is the best way to do this? I have seen a couple of similar posts but not exactly what I need.

```
var loc = window.location;
var currentURL = loc.pathname;

if (currentURL=='/ojs/index.php/index' || currentURL=='/ojs/' ||  currentURL=='/ojs/index.php/index/about' || currentURL=='/ojs/index.php/index/user/register' || currentURL=='/ojs/index.php/index/user/profile' || currentURL=='/ojs/index.php/index/admin/' || currentURL=='/ojs/index.php/index/admin/auth')

loadjscssfile("/ojs/plugins/themes/main-theme/main-theme.css", "css")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```
// unless you were using loc for something else, there is no need to store it,
// just chain to get the pathname
var currentURL = window.location.pathname,
    // create a regular expression that will match all pages under user
    usersPattern = new RegExp('^/ojs/index\.php/index/user/.*');

if (usersPattern.test(currentURL)) {
    loadjscssfile("/ojs/plugins/themes/main-theme/main-theme.css", "css")
}
```

As always is the case with regex, you need to be careful what you are doing to get it right. Here's a short explanation of how this expression works:

- `^` tells it to only match if the string starts with `/ojs/`, etc
- The `\.` in the middle escapes the `.`, telling it that the `.` in `index.php` is a literal dot
- The `.` at the end will match any character
- The `*` following the `.` will match 0 or more instances of the previous character (any character in this case)

I created this regex with the `RegExp` constructor function, but it could also have been done with a regular expression literal. Generally it is a better idea to use a literal but in this case I used the constructor because since it takes a string as an argument I didn't have to escape the `/` characters in the pattern. If we were to do it with a literal, instead of this:

```
usersPattern = new RegExp('^/ojs/index\.php/index/user/.*');
```

It would look like this:

```
usersPattern = /^\/ojs\/index\.php\/index\/user\/.*/;
```

Not needing to escape those `/` makes it a little more readable.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed thank you. This works. Very much appreciated. Will tag so others can find how to do do this or similar using regular expressions.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, an up-vote and accept would be appreciated ;-)